# Get value between 2 spaces

Tags: c#, regex

Given the string value:

```
?*8 100 0
```

I'd like the value between the two spaces (100).

How is it possible to get that value?

Comment: What are the "moving" parts in the input strings? I.e. is the first bit just any old text followed by a space? Are there always three space separated elements within the text? Is the "100" always a number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var value = myString.Split(' ')[1];
```

and if you'd really like to use Regex

```
var value = Regex.Match(myString, @" [^ ]+").Value.Trim();
```

but it adds quite a bit of overhead. Since you said the value is always a number

```
var value = int.Parse(Regex.Match(myString, @" \d+").Value);
```